# In my Springboot project, how to use @Value annotation to get the property value in the Properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot-test

There are two classes and a configuration file, but they are all in the test directory
I want to use the @Value annotation in class A to get the attribute value, and then assemble class A in class B, use the method in class A, I want to output the value obtained from the configuration file, but in fact it is all null
How can i fix it！！！
eg：

class structure:

[image: class structure]

class A

[image: class A]

Class B

[image: Class B]

properteis

[image: properteis]

But if I turn Class A into a test class, I can get the results I want
the result as follow
[image: add the @SpringBootTest on Class A]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: if use @Autowired In Class B,The following error will appear Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.wen.h2.A' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Comment: @sdddog please see the updated answer where you can import A.class.

Comment: @deepakchethan Yes, thank you very much, your suggestion is very correct and solved my confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to autowire `class A` in `class B`. Instead of using the spring managed bean with injected `@Value` you are creating a new class resulting in the variables in `class A` to be null.

```
@SpringBootTest
@Import(A.class)
public class B {

  @Autowire
  private final A a;
}
```